# how do I sum values from a row and the next row, and place them in a column

Tags: vba, excel, sum

So in Column C I have values called *inflow*, starting in Row 3

In Column D, I want to sum the values from the current row and previous row of Column C, (for example. row 4, column D = row 3, column C + row 4, column C) until the end of the sheet

#### screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do this in VBA?

It is easily obtainable through a dragable formula.

In D3 you would obviously have C3.

In D4 you would have `=SUM($C$3:C4)`

Hope it helps. :)

Edit: I might have misinterpreted your question. If it turns out you just want to sum last two values and not all values from the row and up to row three you should just leave out the $ so it would be: D4 `=SUM(C3:C4)`

Dragging it down would give you D5 `=SUM(C4:C5)` and so on.

Edit2:

Okay, I'm not exactly sure what you want, but if you want the formula to be expanded using VBA this should do the trick. Please try it out and let me know if it works for you.

```
Sub autosum()
Dim r As Integer, rmax As Integer

rmax = Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row

For r = 4 To rmax
    Range("D" & r).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R" & r - 1 & "C3:R" & r & "C3)"
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: i want because it depends on the number of rows that have values... it could be 10 rows, or 100.

Comment: By that comment I'm not sure what you mean. Would you like it solved in VBA? And if so, why? Could you give a little more information about the dependence on the number of rows. What would change if you had 100 rows instead of 10 rows?

Comment: yeah sorry i'm not explaining myself correctly. it doesn't change anything, i just wanted for the "dragging" to be done automatically, without having zero values in the column D.

Comment: Automatic dragging can be obtained by doubleclicking the little square in the bottom right corner of the cell. And which zero values are you talking about?

Comment: i know that. but i just want the dragging to happen IF column C has values. i added a screenshot.

Comment: So you want the formula as shown, but vba to expand it to the relevant cells?